# Passing string from a form to another page

Tags: php, database, html

I have tried several plugins to try and pass a text field to another page via PHP and a HTML form. The form works and displays what was entered if there are no text input boxes in the form. The end goal is to be able to pass these variables to an SQL query in the destination page.

```
if (isset($_POST['quantity']))
    echo 'You selected ' . $_POST['quantity'] . '<br />';
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if (!$db) {
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again.';
    exit;
}
mysql_select_db('Stock');
$query = "select * from items limit 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_results == 0)
    echo 'No products found';
else
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        extract($row);
        echo "<form method='post'>";
        echo "ID: <input type='number' name='id' readonly value='$id'><br />";
        echo "Name: <input  type='text' name='name' value='$name'><br />";
        echo "<input type='number' name='quantity' value='$quantity'><br />";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='update'/>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
```

Comment: Your requirement is pass the different form field values to sql table right?

Comment: Your `form` has no `action` attribute.

Comment: Please also keep in mind that the mysql extension is [deprecated](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) as of PHP 5.5. You might want to consider [switching to one of the other APIs](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) to communicate with the database for compatibility in the future.